# Trying to access elements within XML response using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

So - I'm pretty new to JavaScript so this may be a dumb question -

I'm running a POST API call that returns an XML file of the data I need, but I'm unsure how to access specific tags within the XML file from the site that is running the call.

I set my url2 previous to this:

```js
$j.post(url2, function(data, status){
     console.log(data);
    });
```

and it returns:

```html
#document
  <xml>
    <Meta>...</Meta>
      <Result>
        <Recipient>

          ...
```

Which is perfect. However, I'm unsure how I would access the elements within the snippet. For example, within 'Recipient' is a tag called 'userTime'. If I want to access that value with JS, I was hoping for something like:

```js
var ut = data.getElementByTagName('userTime');
```

But that returns: Uncaught TypeError: data.getElementByTagName is not a function

I just don't know what notation I need to use to access elements within the XML return. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `data.getElementByTagName('userTime');` where you have added this line? inside `$j.post`?

Comment: Yes, both within and without (at different times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $j.post(url2, function(data, status){
    var result=data;
});
var data=result.find("Recipient[name='default'][type='primary']"); //XML Parent Node. 'name' is attribute & 'type' is also attribute of node.
```

`var tagdata=data.find('child node tagname').attr('');` `//Node under Parent Node, attr contain`

Comment: This returns: result.find is not a function - I'm loading in jquery 2.1.4, should I be trying a different library?

Comment: May be object of object.find  is not a jQuery object. use browser console debuuger or you can give me proper code so that i'll know the issue.

Comment: Figured it out. It was just that I had jquery in noconflict mode - but hadn't updated this code's $s to reflect that. Everything is working now. Thank you!

Comment: That's great...your welcome @Mathew.. by giving me a flag you can say that i've helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

in this code.

```
$j.post(url2, function(data, status){
```

data is not node. use this code.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"some Url"
    ,dataType:"xml"
    ,method :"post"
}).done(function(data){    
    alert($(data).find("somequery").val());
});
```

Comment: I keep getting this error:  Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function(…)

Comment: Figured it out - I was loading jQuery in noconflict mode due to some other elements in the doc. After changing my $s it worked! Thank you!